# How to access individual variables of a dataset for linear regression?

Tags: r

I'm using the Boston dataset, from the `MASS` package.

I need to predict `crim` using the other 13 predictors separately, and save the slope coefficient of each model.

How I can automate this?

I don't know how to access the variables of the dataset in a `for` loop.

I have tried this to access a single variable using its index:

```
fit1 = lm(Boston[1]~Boston[2])
```

But it returns this:

```
Error en model.frame.default(formula = Boston[1] ~ Boston[2], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'Boston[1]'
```

I want to get access to individual variables in order to use a `for` loop executing 13 different `lm()`s: something like `fit = Boston[i] ~ Boston[i+1]`

Comment: Read `?lm` paying carefully attetion to `data` argument. You can try wrinting `fit1 = lm(crim~zn, data=Boston)` instead.

Comment: yes, I know it. But if I want to access to zn,nox and the all the others in a bucle for... how i can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lm(crim ~ zn, data = Boston)
```

or

```
lm(Boston$crim ~ Boston$zn)
```

use

```
names(Boston)
```

to find out the column names of `Boston`

if you really want to get column by index, the syntax of getting all rows of the 1st column is

```
Boston[,1]
```

Comment: this is all correct, but it would be nice to let people know that `lm(Boston$crim ~ Boston$zn)` will lead to all sorts of annoyances down the line (as well as being ugly): using `data=` is much better practice

Comment: solved, i forget the coma for indicate that i want a column, not a row. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`reformulate()` is a convenient way to set up formulas with specified predictors:

```
 library("MASS")
 get.slope <- function(pred) {
     fit <- lm(reformulate(pred,response="crim"),data=Boston)
     ## unname() to avoid duplicating name of response
     return(unname(coef(fit)[2]))
 }
 sapply(names(Boston)[-1],get.slope)
 ##          zn       indus        chas         nox          rm         age 
 ## -0.07393498  0.50977633 -1.89277655 31.24853120 -2.68405122  0.10778623 
 ##         dis         rad         tax     ptratio       black       lstat 
 ## -1.55090168  0.61791093  0.02974225  1.15198279 -0.03627964  0.54880478 
 ##        medv 
 ## -0.36315992
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `lapply`

```
fits <- lapply(predictors, function(i) {temp <- lm(crim~get(i), data=Boston)$coefficients
                                        names(temp)[2]<- i
                                        return(temp)})
fits
[[1]]
(Intercept)          zn 
 4.45369376 -0.07393498 

[[2]]
(Intercept)       indus 
 -2.0637426   0.5097763 

.... and so on....
```

If you only want a vector or slope coeff, then try:

```
> setNames(sapply(fits, "[[", 2), predictors)
         zn       indus        chas         nox          rm         age         dis         rad 
-0.07393498  0.50977633 -1.89277655 31.24853120 -2.68405122  0.10778623 -1.55090168  0.61791093 
        tax     ptratio       black       lstat        medv 
 0.02974225  1.15198279 -0.03627964  0.54880478 -0.36315992
```